slice_sample producing different samples in grouped .data
Why do the following grouping methods results in different samples. My assumption was that the grouping results to similar samples?
small <- data.frame(
  id = 1:100,
  gender = rep(c('male', 'female'))
)

set.seed(123)
small |> 
  group_by(gender) |> 
  slice_sample(n = 10, replace = F)

set.seed(123)
small |> 
  slice_sample(n = 10, replace = F, by = gender)


Interesting. I don't have the complete answer, but seems related to the difference in the sorting. See ?dplyr_by :
"When used with .by, summarise(), reframe(), and slice() all maintain the ordering of the existing data. This is different from group_by(), which has always sorted the group keys in ascending order."
If the dataframe is build in alphabetical order, ex with  gender = rep(c('a.male', 'b.female')) , the result of the two methods will be the same [on my machine].

@VinceGreg I tried out with the ex  gender = rep(c('a.male', 'b.female')) and the two methods resulted in the same samples. The question is why is it that when we add a prefix before the levels it works but it doesn't work with the actual factors, which can also be arranged alphabetically? and Generally should the two methods give the same results?

In my understanding, the same randoms numbers [since set.seed is used] will be use for the sampling of the first group , and others will be used for the second group. With group_by ,  "male" is the second group , so the second set of random number will be use; and with .by, its the first group, so the first set of random number will be use.

Basically when you use .by the groups are sorted by order of first appearance and when you use group_by(), the groups are sorted. Since we see 'small' before 'female', this explains the difference in the results.
My package timeplyr actually has arguments to control this behaviour.
Edit: You can also control this behaviour through fgroup_by(order =)
As to why the actual samples are different within each group, my best guess has is even though the seed is the same, because the sampling is done in a different by-group order, this will affect which samples are drawn.
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
small <- data.frame(
  id = 1:100,
  gender = rep(c('male', 'female'))
)

set.seed(123)
res1 <- small |> 
  group_by(gender) |> 
  slice_sample(n = 10, replace = F)

set.seed(123)
res2 <- small |> 
  slice_sample(n = 10, replace = F, by = gender)

library(timeplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'timeplyr'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:dplyr':
#> 
#>     desc

res3 <- small |> 
  fslice_sample(n = 10, replace = F, .by = gender, seed = 123, sort_groups = TRUE)
res4 <- small |> 
  fslice_sample(n = 10, replace = F, .by = gender, seed = 123, sort_groups = FALSE)

identical(as.data.frame(res1), res3)
#> [1] TRUE
identical(as.data.frame(res2), res4)
#> [1] TRUE

res5 <- small |> 
  fgroup_by(gender, order = TRUE) |> 
  fslice_sample(n = 10, replace = F, seed = 123)
res6 <- small |> 
  fgroup_by(gender, order = FALSE) |> 
  fslice_sample(n = 10, replace = F, seed = 123)

identical(as.data.frame(res1), as.data.frame(res5))
#> [1] TRUE
identical(as.data.frame(res2), as.data.frame(res6))
#> [1] TRUE

Created on 2024-08-01 with reprex v2.0.2
